# Autofac RegisterAssemblyTypes tries to resolve all public types

Tags: autofac

Quick question: I've been using autofac with asp.net core in a project and I've noticed that it tries to resolve all types during configuration after updating it to the latest nuget package (going from Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 5.0.1 to 7.0.2). Btw, here's the code that was being used to register the types:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Utilizador).Assembly)
               .AsImplementedInterfaces()
               .AsSelf();
```

Until now, I wasn't seeing this behavior. The problem with this new approach is that it will try to resolve types that will never be injected through DI. For instance, it complains about public classes that don't have public constructors event though those classes will never be created through DI.

Can someone point me to when this change happened?

Does this mean that now I must filter the types I need explicitly?

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify _by editing your question_: What does the code look like when you register the assembly types? When you say "it tries to resolve all types during configuration" - what does that mean? Where's the code where you see the resolve occurring? Is it actually resolving or is it just registering? Again, please update that data in the question, not down here in comments.

Comment: It also wouldn't hurt to explain which packages got updated. There's not an Autofac 7.0.2 but there is an Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection 7.0.2. What else changed? What else got updated?

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing new.

You can filter those out with something like below:

```
   builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ThisAssembly)
                .Where(type => type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public).Any())
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```